# Gamecube color/sound

Tags: nintendo-gamecube

[image]

So, to start this off. It's been almost 3 years since my family and I have had our gamecube hooked up. We could never find our power cord for it, so of course, we assumed we lost it. We kept trying to find another one. Never could, until tonight.
I found our power cord in a tin bucket in our basement, and bought one of those video/audio cords are Jay's CD's and Hobbys. I thought it'd be a nice suprise for my mother on Christmas since her and I are huge Zelda fans and have not been able to play our games in awhile. 
I finally have everything hooked up, and thankfully it turns on, but the color is in black and white and there's no sound. As you see in the picture, if it has hopefully shown up, that I only have the colors yellow and red hooked up, because I only have 2 middle pieces that connect them. So I'm thinking that it's only lacking color and audio because I don't have the whites hooked up, but I wanted to ask and make sure.
Any comments revolving around this issue, would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Missing from the description and pictures is what you plugged it into on the TV. Could you look behind the TV and tell us the name of the ports?

Comment: Red and white are (stereo) audio, while yellow is video. Having the white unplugged shouldn't affect anything the way you're describing.

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/132648/171616 ?

Comment: @StevenSidedDie, I cannot look behind the television because it's mountain to the wall, and I fear if I move it, it will fall and break.